# HTML open file from another drive

Tags: html, file, hyperlink, drive

I have a question about opening a file that is located on another drive with HTML.

I have this now:

```
<a href="file:///E:/trailer.mp4">trailer</a>
```

But when I click the link nothing happens? But when I past it into my browser, it works. Why is this not working with HTML and how can I get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The file location slash is wrong, try this:

```
<a href="file:///E:\trailer.mp4">trailer</a>
```

and will work

Comment: Thanks! It does work now, but it's not working with an apache server?

Comment: For use this in apache server, use only the position file, like as:

<a href="trailers/trailer.mp4">trailer</a>

Answer (score 0):

Change the slash after E:
Click on the text bar in Explorer in Windows and copy to make sure you get the correct string.